# #NA14 outage - Find out on which instance are my ISV package subscribers

Tags: package, isv, instance, trust

NA14 just was offline for nearly a full day and data of many hours of data is just lost. Besides pointing our customers to trust.salesforce.com as an ISV we want to proactivly react and contanct affected customers.

Is there any way to find out which subscribert of our packages is on which instance? This information exist from in the Subscriber View but there is no way to query that or create custom list view by instance.

[image]

Comment: On basis of which information you want to grab the instance information??

Comment: The information which subscriber is on which instance exists. To prove that I showed the subscriber tab. I'm looking for a way to get all subscribers on instance XYZ. Eighter by doing a query or having listviews for all instances.

Comment: This might be helpful [LMA: Get a list of all Subscribers with version installed](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114024/lma-get-a-list-of-all-subscribers-with-version-installed)

Comment: We have the LMA installed but I didn't know of this field. Awesome. Can you convert it to an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the given link is useful so converting it into answer:

[LMA: Get a list of all subscribers with version installed](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114024/lma-get-a-list-of-all-subscribers-with-version-installed)